# Add field to existing documents over million records

Tags: go, couchbase, sql++

**Scenario**

We have over 5 million document in a bucket and all of it has nested JSON with a simple uuid key. We want to add one extra field to ALL of the documents.

Example

```
ee6ae656-6e07-4aa2-951e-ea788e24856a
{
   "field1":"data1",
   "field2":{
      "nested_field1":"data2"
   }
}
```

After adding extra field

```
ee6ae656-6e07-4aa2-951e-ea788e24856a
{
   "field1":"data1",
   "field3":"data3",
   "field2":{
      "nested_field1":"data2"
   }
}
```

It has only one Primary Index: `CREATE PRIMARY INDEX idx FOR bucket`.

**Problem**

It takes ages. We tried it with n1ql, `UPDATE bucket SET field3 = data3`. Also sub-document mutation. But all of it takes hours. It's written in Go so we could put it into a goroutine, but it's still too much time.

**Question**

Is there any solution to reduce that time?

Comment: Can you break it up into multiple iterations? If there was a performant way to run it on, say, 5000 documents at a time? Would that be okay? Or must every document be updated within a short window of time? And if so, what is that window of time? What is "fast enough" for you?

Comment: @MatthewGroves if it runs in an hour time range that would be perfect I guess. But there are two cases, it's fails, or it's running for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need to add new field, not modifying any existing field it is better to use SDKs SUBDOC API vs N1QL UPDATE (It is whole document update and require fetch the document).

The Best option will be Use N1QL get the document keys then use
SDK SUBDOC API to add the field you need. You can use reactive API(asynchronously)

You have 5M documents and have primary index use following

```
val = ""
In loop
    SELECT RAW META().id FROM mybucket WHERE META().id > $val  LIMIT 10000;
    SDK SUBDOC update
    val = last value from the SELECT
```

https://blog.couchbase.com/offset-keyset-pagination-n1ql-query-couchbase/

Comment: We did nearly the same, but this RAW META().id was better. I guess it is the max what we could get out from Couchbase. So we had to realise that the Couchbase isn't suitable to doing that kind of purpose.

Comment: couchbase eventing service might be option

Answer (score 2):

The Eventing Service can be quite performant for these sort of enrichment tasks. Even a low end system should be able to do 5M rows in under two (2) minutes.

```
// Note src_bkt is an alias to the source bucket for your handler
// in read+write mode supported for version 6.5.1+, this uses DCP 
// and can be 100X more performant than N1QL.

function OnUpdate(doc, meta) {
    // optional filter to be more selective
    // if (!doc.type && doc.type !== "mytype") return;

    // test if we already have the field we want to add
    if (doc.field3) return;

    doc.field3 = "data3";
    src_bkt[meta.id] = doc;
}
```

For more details on Eventing refer to https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-overview.html I typically enrich 3/4 of a billion documents.  The  Eventing function will also run faster (enrich more documents per second) if you increase the number of workers in your Eventing function's setting from say 3 to 16 provided you have 8+ physical cores on your Eventing node.

I tested the above Eventing function and it enriches 5M documents (modeled on your example) on my non-MDS single node couchbase test system (12 cores at 2.2GHz) in just 72 seconds. Obviously if you have a real multi node cluster it will be faster (maybe all 5M docs in just 5 seconds).

Comment: That sounds awesome, we will give it a try, thanks.